# Python Selenium - Can't locate element by attribute of data-title

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation, css-selectors

**What I am trying to do**:
Quite simply, use Selenium to select a specific day in a calendar, via the attribute of the day element.

**The structure of the web page**:
The days of a month exist in a calendar table, which should also be fairly standard. Snapshot of the calendar table: [dayTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMm32.png)
Snapshot of the HTML source code:[dayTableHTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FjIe.png)

**What has worked**:
I have no problem locating/selecting a certain day element via direct path, either via XPath or CSS selector. For example, if I want to select day "6", I will just use the following code. Both work fine.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(4)')
```

**What is not working**: I'd like to select a day just by its identifiers. As you can see in the source code picture embedded above, there is no class or id names that's unique for each day. The attribute of "data-title" seems to be the perfect solution, since its value is the position of the day within the calendar table. Day "6", for example, has a data-title of "r1c3".

So I try to select the element again via the attribute value. And this is where I have been stuck. I have been given SyntaxError of invalid syntax. The code is as followed:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table > tbody td[data-title='r1c3']')
```

The pointing arrow points to the 3 within 'r1c3', but I really don't know what's wrong with this line of code.

**Is it because the attribute of 'data-title' has a hyphen in its name, and that is difficult for Python/Selenium to handle?** Then how do I properly escape the hyphen? It's confusing as many related articles use attributes with hyphenated names, and there didn't seem to be any issue or escaping involved.

**Is it because there are multiple tr nodes under the table node, and multiple td nodes under a tr node, and my code does not lead me to the specific td I want?** But isn't that what the attribute specification there is for?

Please help solve the mystery. I will very much appreciate your magic. Thank you!!

Comment: `//table/tbody/tr\[2]/td[4]` The backslash works?

Comment: Hi John! Sorry I added that when I first tried to type in the code into the question box. Not knowing that code can be formatted separately, I put the code in as a normal text line, with the backslash in there to escape the "[2]", since it was being directed to the second image I uploaded...Then cruisepandey helped me formatted it, and the backslash appeared after that. I have now made the edit.:) Thank you so much for answering and for pointing it out! This is my first stackoverflow question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this did not work for you : `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table > tbody td[data-title='r1c3']')`

Then this should work :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table > tbody td[data-title='r1c3']")
```

It is not because of hyphen. It is because of single quote which you have used , just replace the **outer single quotes** with **double quotes** , reset seems to be fine.

**Is it because there are multiple tr nodes under the table node, and multiple td nodes under a tr node, and my code does not lead me to the specific td I want?** :
No it a **invalid syntax error** , because **python** could not parse it. The locator you have used it quite good.

Comment: Ah, the double quotes worked! One step closer to victory. Thank you so much for answering, cruisepandey! This is my first question on stackoverflow too, so thank you for helping me edit the code as well!

Comment: @xuanzee : No problem , you really explained your problem very well. I appreciate it. Would you mind accepting this as an answer , if that worked for you? In case you want to accept it, simply click on check mark which is just under the down vote button.  Or in case you want to go through accepted answer , then you can follow :  (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @xuanzee : Thank you. Have a nice day.